# Cannot install ros-melodic-rostime on Archlinux

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the instalation guide for Arch, the first thing you are told to do is execute `pikaur -S ros-melodic-desktop-full` but this ended in an error when installing `ros-melodic-rostime` package.
I tried to install just that package and this was the given error.
Project 'rostime' tried to find library '-lpthread'. The library is neither a target nor built/installed properly.

It uses `/usr/bin/cc` and `/usr/bin/c++`, I changed them to `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/g++` but is still giving the same error.

And the output of `find /usr/lib -name "*libpthread*"` is:

```
/usr/lib/libpthread.so
/usr/lib/libpthread.a
/usr/lib/libpthread-2.28.so
/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
```

So I have libpthread installed

Y have already solved one error like this yesterday, it was just downgrading cmake, so now I have

```
cmake --version
cmake version 3.12.4
```

And just with that I was able to install the package `ros-melodic-class-loader` that gave me the same error before downgrading cmake, but now I don't know what to do, I have been searching for hours but found nothing.

If someone has any idea I appreciate so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311753/cannot-install-ros-melodic-rostime-on-archlinux/) by [NelsonCandela](https://answers.ros.org/users/39259/nelsoncandela/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2019-01-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-01**:
This is probably related to #q311685 if not a duplicate.

**Comment by [NelsonCandela](https://answers.ros.org/users/39259/nelsoncandela/) on 2019-01-01**:
I had already read it, its why I downgraded cmake from 3.13 to 3.12 as it says, and with that I was able to install ros-melodic-class-loader and probably another bunch of packages that were going to fail with 3.13 but rostime gives me the exact same error that it did class-loader but with cmake<3.13

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-02**:
@Allenh1 already mentions in #q311685 that his patching/work is probably incomplete. See also [ros/ros-overlay#711](https://github.com/ros/ros-overlay/issues/711).

**Comment by [NelsonCandela](https://answers.ros.org/users/39259/nelsoncandela/) on 2019-01-02**:
I didn't read enough, so sorry for wasting your time, it was just rebuild the package ros-melodic-cpp-common and I could successfully install rso-melodic-rostime

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-02**:
No need to apologise.

Please post your last comment as an answer (extend it a little) and perhaps refer to the relevant comments by @allenh1 or in the issue on `ros/ros-overlay` I linked to so future readers have an easier time to solve it themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved, for me was a quite simple solution.

1. Install the version [3.12.3](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/tag/v3.12.3) of cmake, it's the one that I used, it might also work with [3.12.4](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/tag/v3.12.4) or other versions, but I can't confirm it.
2. Rebuild the package `ros-melodic-cpp-common`. As I don't know how to just rebuild something, I first removed it with `pikaur -Rs ros-melodic-cpp-common` and then reinstalled it with `pikaur -S ros-melodic-cpp-common`.
3. Now you should be able to install `ros-melodic-rostime` with `pikaur -S ros-melodic-rostime`.

I used `pikaur` as AUR helper, but it should work with any other, like `yay` for example.

[Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/311685/) was were I obtained all the information.

---

Originally posted by [NelsonCandela](https://answers.ros.org/users/39259/nelsoncandela/) with karma: 36 on 2019-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-02**:
Final comment: I would consider all of this a work-around, not a solution. IIUC, upstream CMake changed something in a `find..(..)` script which adds `-lpthread` to the `LIBRARIES` variable, instead of making it a proper compiler flag. That is why things break, and it should be fixed *there*. ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-02**:
.. This is not a ROS or Catkin problem.

See [the Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=915148) report for more background.

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2019-01-17**:
Ran into this same issue. I also ended up needing to downgrade to boost and boost-libs 1.68.0-2 instead of the current 1.69.0. A few packages were looking for libboost_signal.so, which appears gone in 1.69.0?

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2019-01-17**:
While maybe not a ROS bug, others are wrestling with this [here](https://github.com/ros/ros-overlay/issues/711) too.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-17**:
@jwhendy: the boost downgrade sounds like a separate issue. Let's not conflate them.

> others are wrestling with this here too.

Yes, that is `ros/ros-overlay#711` that was referred to earlier.

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2019-01-20**:
Agreed. I now think that since I downgraded `cmake` via arch archive binaries, it was likely compiled against previous versions of `boost` at that time.